# Do any distributed computing platforms use a common connection protocol?

Tags: erlang, protocols, distributed-computing

I found Erlang's 'distribution protocol' outlining the handshake process between nodes here: http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/erl_dist_protocol.html

I'm writing my own toy platform and I'd like to make it compatible with others if possible. Is there a common protocol that is widely implemented or do most platforms take Erlang's approach and force you to implement their specific protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with any common protocols for distributed systems. I know Erlang only supports one 'distribution protocol' out of the box, but of course you can implement your own protocol in Erlang if necessary.